# How can I expand results in a MixPanel?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel, jql

Following is the result of my MixPanel query:

```
location      visitors
----------------------
location-1    A,B,C
location-3    E
location-4    F,H
```

But, I need it as follows:

```
location      visitors
----------------------
location-1    A
location-1    B
location-1    C
location-3    E
location-4    F
location-4    H
```

My code is as follows:

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2020-03-12',
    to_date:   '2020-03-13'
  }).map(function (event) {
    return {
      'location': event.location,
      'people_visited': event.people_visited
    };
  });
}
```

I have looked into MixPanel's documentation, but cannot come to a solution:
https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/jql-api-reference

Please help!